# Maven commands to deploy and run osgi bundles

Tags: maven, osgi, equinox

I have my my osgi bundles built. I would like to know is there any maven commands available to  deploy and run these bundles in equinox, as we have for jboss-as (mvn jboss-as:deploy & mvn jboss-as:undeploy)? If yes, any good tutorials for the same? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use a build tool to type commands into an interactive runtime environment?

Comment: @Neil Bartlett I am trying to write a shell script of maven commands that would execute on the server and thats why I want the controlling of bundles to be done by maven commands. Is there any way for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Pax Runner support to your Maven projects building the bundles (works best when the whole bundle-based app is being built via a reactor POM), and use `mvn install pax:provision` to deploy and run the bundles in Equinox via a proper configuration of the Maven pax plugin.

The [Maven Cookbook section 1.2. Generating an OSGi Project with Maven](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mcookbook/reference/sect-osgi-generate-project.html) has a description how to create a new empty project with Pax Runner support, and [with some work you can retrofit its configuration to an existing project](http://pbrada.tumblr.com/post/46708711391/retrofitting-an-osgi-eclipse-project-to-maven-and-pax) -- the description is a bit lengthy so I moved it to a separate blog post.

[osgi](/questions/tagged/osgi) [maven](/questions/tagged/maven)

Answer (score -1):

Try `install <bundle-jar>`. This should work. See http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/06/osgi-using-maven-equinox.html for details

Comment: Is'nt that an equinox command? I am searching for Maven commands to execute. In the case of jboss if i run the command "mvn jboss-as:deploy" from command prompt , my bundle will automatically deployed in jboss container.